# how to interpret this rule in yacc? "::" { yycolumn + = yyleng; return (TYPESEPnumber); }

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

I have to fix a program written in yacc (a parser generator) to work in conjunction with a provided file "lexer.l" to create a small interpreter (I  cannot make any change in lexer.l). And, I found this line in the lexer.l file that I don't know how to interpret

here are the unknown rules ...

```
%%

"::" { yycolumn + = yyleng; return (TYPESEPnumber); }

%%
```

Could someone help me to understand how `"::"` works in this case?
So, the following test program should work: 
program xx is
{

```
 a :: int;
 a = 5;
 print "My job is to test the print function. Here is an int: " , 55 , " and the 
 value of var a: " , a;
```

}

I could make my yacc interpreter work file if the test file was simple like this:

```
int a;

a = 5;

etc etc..
```

but not in this take of lines `" a :: int; "` in my test file. Help..
 Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It means that the token `::` is sent to the parser as `TYPESEPnumber`. (I have no idea why anyone would add `number` to the end of a token id.)

So I would expect the parser prologue to include:

```
%token TYPESEPnumber "::"
```

And a production something like

```
declaration: ID "::" type ';'
```

(Some professors don't use bison's convenient syntax for aliasing clunky token identifiers to easily-understood quoted strings. But it makes grammars much easier to read.)